# Java CodingBat Logic teaParty?

Tags: java

I am obviously missing an "if" statement but I am not sure how to cover if tea or candy is not double of each other:

[Java > Logic-1 > teaParty](http://codingbat.com/prob/p177181)

We are having a party with amounts of tea and candy. Return the int outcome of the party encoded as 0=bad, 1=good, or 2=great. A party is good (1) if both tea and candy are at least 5. However, if either tea or candy is at least double the amount of the other one, the party is great (2). However, in all cases, if either tea or candy is less than 5, the party is always bad (0).

```
teaParty(6, 8) → 1
teaParty(3, 8) → 0
teaParty(20, 6) → 2
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public int teaParty(int tea, int candy) {

  if(tea < 5 || candy < 5)
     return 0;

  if(tea == 5 && candy == 5)
     return 1;

  if(tea != 5 && candy != 5)
     return 1;

  if(candy * 2 >= tea)
     return 2;

  if(tea * 2 >= candy)
     return 2;


return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I am receiving:

```
Expected    This Run        
teaParty(6, 8) → 1  1   OK      
teaParty(3, 8) → 0  0   OK      
teaParty(20, 6) → 2 1   X       
teaParty(12, 6) → 2 1   X       
teaParty(11, 6) → 1 1   OK      
teaParty(11, 4) → 0 0   OK      
teaParty(4, 5) → 0  0   OK      
teaParty(5, 5) → 1  1   OK      
teaParty(6, 6) → 1  1   OK      
teaParty(5, 10) → 2 2   OK      
teaParty(5, 9) → 1  2   X       
teaParty(10, 4) → 0 0   OK      
teaParty(10, 20) → 2    1   X       
other tests
X
```

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about.

Comment: how can you expect `1` when `teaParty(5, 9)`?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I am suspect of your second `if` statement. Only calls where exactly one of the values is 5 (but not both) will ever get past that statement, which doesn't seem to be your intent.

Comment: You should actually ask a question. That includes clearly describing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added the question to the updated post.

Comment: What does the teaParty method have to do with the InOrderEquals question? They seem very unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have some redundant and incorrect cases.  Here is a simpler version:

```
public int teaParty(int tea, int candy) {
  if(tea < 5 || candy < 5)  // your first case was correct
     return 0;

  if(candy * 2 <= tea || tea * 2 <= candy)  // must be <= not >=
     return 2;

  return 1;  // after you handle the first two cases, just return 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code if you would like a simple compact one line solution without using Ifs and in your code some conditions checked are redundant which might be causing the errors

```
 public int teaParty(int tea, int candy)
 {
    return (tea < 5 || candy < 5) ? 0: (tea >= 2 * candy || candy >= 2 * tea) ? 2 : 1;
 }
```

Comment: To be fair, the conditional operator `?` is practically the same as `if ... else`, so you are using `ifs`. Besides that, simplest and shortest solution, should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
teaParty(20, 6) → 2 1   X       
teaParty(12, 6) → 2 1   X
```

These two are firing as 1 because neither equals 5. They are triggered by

```
if(tea != 5 && candy != 5)
     return 1;
```

As for

```
teaParty(5, 9) → 1  2   X
```

That is firing because it passes the "five checks" that return 1, and candy * 2 (which is 10) is greater than tea (which is 9), so it hits

```
 if(candy * 2 >= tea)
     return 2;
```

However, you don't really have a question to ask here. What is your objective? Can you provide more context? Perhaps we can use that to find the true error, not just the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain why you are getting the output you are but I don't know what you want it to be.

```
if(tea != 5 && candy != 5)
 return 1;
```

This if statement means that if both tea and candy are not 5 then return 1. This is the 3rd if statement you have so to get here you need to pass these 2

```
if(tea < 5 || candy < 5)
     return 0;

  if(tea == 5 && candy == 5)
     return 1;
```

So if tea and candy are both greater than or equal to 5 it will fail the first one and if either tea or candy isn't 5 it will fail the second.

in these cases

```
teaParty(20, 6) → 2 1   X       
teaParty(12, 6) → 2 1   X 
teaParty(10, 20) → 2 1   X
```

tea = 20, 12, 10 all greater than 5 and not 5
candy = 6, 20 all greater than 5 and not 5
so you get the 3rd if

this case

```
teaParty(5, 9) → 1  2   X
```

tea = 5
candy = 9

so you get the 4th if

```
  if(candy * 2 >= tea) (9*2 >= 5) true
     return 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(tea != 5 && candy != 5)` is executed before all your tests to check if one is the double (at least) of the other. Either remove that `if` statement or move it so you can get your double checks to work. Something like :

```
if(tea < 5 || candy < 5)
    return 0;

if(tea == 5 && candy == 5)
    return 1;

if(tea != 5 && candy != 5)
{
    if((candy * 2 >= tea) || (tea * 2 >= candy))
         return 2;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should try your solution [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p177181) and submit one that works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int teaParty(int tea, int candy) {

  if (tea>=5 && candy>=5) {
    if (tea>=candy*2 || candy>=tea*2) { return 2; }
    else { return 1; }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. Clearer logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int teaParty(int tea, int candy) {
  if (tea >= 5 && candy >=5) {
    if (tea / candy >= 2 || candy / tea >= 2) {
      return 2;
    }
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( tea < 5 || candy < 5 )
    return 0;
if ( tea >= candy * 2 || candy >= tea * 2 )
    return 2;
if ( tea >= 5 && candy >= 5 )
    return 1;
else return 0;
```